# Can a method related to "Weisfeiler-Lehman Method" provide better time complexity for Graph Isomorphism than existing result?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, algorithms, graph-isomorphism

*[Cai-Furer-Immerman](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.32.4863)  showed that the W-L(Weisfeiler-Lehman )
hierarchy cannot distinguish general graphs except at linear dimension.*

Even besides CFI's result, there is good reason to believe that purely
combinatorial methods cannot work for general graphs. Even for the
"bounded parameter" families for which we have polynomial-time
algorithms, the group-theory method is generally required.

Furthermore,
the "algebraic structure" of the GI problem seems essential to its
potential tractability, since every generalization of GI that destroys
the algebraic structure is NP-complete.

**But I can not find any error in [this quasi-polynomial claim](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/296704876_An_Ofracnlog_2n2log_2n2_Graph_Isomorphism_Algorithm_for_a_Restricted_Class_of_Graph), which proposition is wrong?**

The algorithm does not depend on W-L method entirely though .

This post is motivated by [this query](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32237/is-anyone-aware-of-a-counter-example-to-the-dharwadker-tevet-graph-isomorphism-a) .

Link of the claim :['Quasi polynomial claim for a restricted class Graph Isomorphism'](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/296704876_An_Ofracnlog_2n2log_2n2_Graph_Isomorphism_Algorithm_for_a_Restricted_Class_of_Graph)

Comment: the [link](https://www.academia.edu/15102354/Quasi-polynomial_claim_of_Graph_Isomorphism) now comes up 404

Comment: the paper and question do not cite Weisfeiler-Lehman except by name. what is the ref?

Answer (score 2):

To select a couple things out of many to pick on:

Prop 2.4: The proof begins by saying "To determine whether $G \simeq H$, try all possible permutations of $G$. Assume $G \simeq H$. It will take $T(n)$ number of permutations necessary to reorder $G$ exactly like $H$ for $n$ vertices, if they are isomorphic." Where does this $T(n)$ number come from? Is this how they are defining it? There are $n!$ possible permutations. It also talks about "trying all possible $n$ vertices of $G$ as the $n$th vertex of $H$", it is not clear what this means.  You can put vertex $i$ from $G$ in position $j$ and test if that can be extended to an isomorphism? It is not well explained, requires permutations of other vertices to see if it will work, and it is possible that many vertices can be put here with the local structure carrying over, but not extending to an isomorphism.  All the surrounding context suggests there are deep problems related to the evaluation of the complexity.

Prop 2.5: This is essentially only proved for the special example given earlier in the paper.  Also, it does not address the complexity involved in actually partitioning the graph as described in the method.

Another big red flag is the title.  It states that this is the number of matrices to check.  But what is the complexity of checking each matrix? It is not a constant, it will depend on $n$.

The most basic way to test is to write an implementation of the algorithm.  Does it actually detect that two isomorphic graphs are isomorphic?

Comment: "Another big red flag is the title. It states that this is the number of matrices to check. But what is the complexity of checking each matrix? It is not a constant, it will depend on n." to check each matrix you need a $O(n^2)$ process .

Comment: have you noticed that proposition 1.1 - 2.4  are for based on method 1.2 ?  before you read  propositions  you should read how graphs are partitioned in method 1.2 (later 1.1). you write about n! possibilities , it is not possible if you follow method 1.2 ;   $T(n)$ is number which depends on $n$, since method 1.2 is a recursive fucntion, $T(n)$ is used. How $T(n)$ is used , it is shown in the proof(proof may be right or wrong). I think you have overlooked some part , you can not get everything at first glance, can you? can anyone? Please , have a thorough look.

Comment: I did read the method.  But it specifically says "try all possible permutations".  If I am assuming that the graph has been partitioned somehow, and I am only supposed to try *some* permutations based on that, it is not clear.  Also, method 1.2: it is not clear what I end up with at the end of this.  In addition, it seems like I lose a vertex at each step. Plus in 2.1 you state "each column of  $C_{2y-2}$ has constant number of 1", you seem to be assuming these graphs are all regular. But there is no clear reason for this to be true... (actually I can find counterexamples)

Comment: ' But it specifically says "try all possible permutations". '....  :)  it means that   $H$ is ordered according to Method 1.2 , so $G$ needs to find all possible permutation following / according to Method 1.2. You may  try  considering  about all  possible permutations of $G$,  possible according to Method 1.2. The number would be the same as stated on the document.  Also 1.1 to 2.4 are true for regular graphs(as described assumed) only, if the graphs are irregular we will use method 1.1, consider propositions as they are assumed. You can ask later, how they are merged or managed together !

Comment: An updated version is uploaded, see if anything has changed.

Comment: I think the best advice to give is: Is the algorithm described clearly enough to be implemented? Then implement it, does it work? Only then is it worthwhile to analyze the complexity...